# sed with vertical bar?

Tags: sed

I have a list

```
>ANARCI-HMM_human_167.7|pdb|7EPU|A
>ANARCI-HMM_alpaca_173.7|pdb|7EVY|E
>ANARCI-HMM_alpaca_172.8|pdb|7F2O|S
>ANARCI-HMM_alpaca_171.8|pdb|7F4F|S
>ANARCI-HMM_alpaca_173.6|pdb|7F8W|D
```

I want to remove from `ANARCI` to the first vertical bar `|`.

expecting

```
>pdb|7EPU|A
>pdb|7EVY|E
>pdb|7F2O|S
>pdb|7F4F|S
>pdb|7F8W|D
```

I tried

```
sed 's/ANARCI.*\|//g'
```

but didn't work.

Do you have any idea how to sed in this case?

Comment: Why not use `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[A-Z][^|]*|//' input_file
>pdb|7EPU|A
>pdb|7EVY|E
>pdb|7F2O|S
>pdb|7F4F|S
>pdb|7F8W|D
```

Comment: This is not matching `ANARCI` like in your examples but any text  starting with uppercase

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove from ANARCIat the first vertical bar |, try this:

```
sed 's/ANARCI[^|]*\|//g'
```

or

```
sed 's/ANARCI[^|]*\|(.*)/\1\2/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed 's/ANARCI[^|]*\|//g'
```

to not match the `|`

Comment: with GNU BRE, you don't need to escape `|` to have a literal. Also, in this case, no need to use `g`

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `sed` code.

```
sed -E 's/(.*)ANARCI[^|]*\|(.*)/\1\2/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above `sed` code.

- Using `-E` option of `sed` to enable ERE(extended regular expression) for program.
- Then using `sed`'s capability of storing matched patterns into temporary buffer memory(called capturing groups), by which we can make use of caught values while substitution.
- Creating 2 capturing groups here, 1st which has everything before ANARCI string and 2nd capturing group which has everything after first pipe(matching from ANARCI to till first pipe) to get rest of part after first pipe.
- While performing substitution substituting line with 1st and 2nd capturing group.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** You could use `awk` for this task also, use `match` function of `awk`. Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` and matching only part which you don't required in output, while printing the values printing everything else apart from matched part(which is not required).

```
awk 'match($0,/ANARCI[^|]*/){print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Adding 1 more solution in `awk`, where setting field separators to: from string `ANARCI` to till first occurrence of pipe. Then in main `awk` program printing 1st and last field, required values as per shown samples.

```
awk -v FS="ANARCI[^\\\\|]*\\\\|" '{print $1 $NF}' Input_file
```

Comment: No need to use sed with GNU ERE regex since GNU BRE regex has already the same features (you need only to escape the metacharacters). For POSIX compliance, note that backreferences are supported only in BRE mode .